# How to get the last number in a string using regex?

Tags: java

The string I have is -- `20 of 568 matches`. I want `568` to be picked up and displayed.

What regex can I use to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried anything with code? post any code you tried'

Comment: (\\d+)(?!.*\\d)--this is returning--20 of  matches

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getSpecSubString("20 matches out of 568"));
}

private static int getSpecSubString(String string) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        String str = matcher.group();
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }

    return -1; // NO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
        String sentence = "20 matches out of 568";
        String lastWord = sentence.replaceAll("^.*?(\\w+)\\W*$", "$1");
        System.out.println(lastWord);
}
```

another way without regular expression is

```
String[] all = data.split(" ");
System.out.println(all[all.length-1]);
```

Comment: Hi Neel, My text is--20 of 568 matches sorry for the earlier entry. Can you suggest the Regex for this and also, please let me know the logic on how to build Regex-- I am ne to this JAVA world